# Поиск по неполному совпадению в ключах массива

Tags: php, массивы

```
<?
# Значение, которое необходимо найти
$search = 'Ан';

# Массив
$array  = array('Иван' => array(60), 'Анна' => array(70), 'Анастасия' => array(50));
?>
```

Как в данном случае по запросу **Ан** найти в массиве и вывести два совпадающих значения?

1. Анна 70
2. Анастасия 50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$search = 'Ан';

$array  = array('Иван' => array(60), 'Анна' => array(70), 'Анастасия' => array(50));   

echo '<ol>';
 foreach ($array as  $key=>$val){    
    if (strpos($key, $search)!==false){          
          echo  '<li>' . $key . ' ' . $val[0] . '</li>';      
    }    
  }
echo '</ol>';
```